# How to limit the user not to enter number greater than four?

Tags: angularjs

I have a input text box,where only numbers are allowed to enter.numbers="numbers-only" is the directive that prevents users to enter anything rather than numbers.Now I should not allow the user to enter the number with value more than 4.Plz help
HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='pat' id='pat' ng-model='dpmArr.pt_no'  class='form-control' numbers-only="numbers-only">
```

Comment: Hi! any update on this topic?

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 attributes that allow you to add a minimum and maximum to your input they are `min`and `max`

so just add `max ="4"` into your tags

Answer (score 2):

#### Your Own directive

You can add another directive like this:

in `html`:

```
<input with-max-limit max-limit="9" type="text" ng-required="true"  name="search" ng-model="value">
```

And in your `js`:

```
.directive("withMaxLimit", function () {
        return {
            require: ["ngModel"],
            restrict: "A",
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
                var modelName = $attrs.ngModel;
                var maxLimit = parseInt($attrs.maxLimit, 10);
                $scope.$watch(modelName, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    if (newValue && (newValue.length > maxLimit || newValue.indexOf(' ') >= 0)) {
                        $scope[modelName] = oldValue;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

Take into account that it is draft version and you could easily modify it.

Also pay attention to **Angular's naming convention** that directive has name `withMaxLimit` but in `html` it will be `with-max-limit`.

#### AngularJS Filter

Also take a look at Angular's [`limitTo` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo).

Answer (score 1):

Use an input with `type="number"` and an `max=4` attribute:

```
<input type="number" max="4" name="input" ng-model="example.value">
```

Ref. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bnumber%5D

Comment: Could be issues in older version of the browsers but it's ok if you don't need them :)

Answer (score 0):

how are you applying the behavior with the numbers? I ask because maybe you could try to follow the same pattern. Otherwise, I think there are more than one option according to your needs. For instance, if the user introduces one number greater than 4, what should be the expected behavior? Return an error, block and don´t write anything in the input,...

Depending on it, you could choose to add [$parsers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$parsers) to the ngModelController or simply block the default behavior of the key by checking what is the key that has been pressed.